# Change background color of individual div when clicked in a row of 5 and reset when another is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, colors, background

I have found alot of useful answers on this website when i have got stuck  and now i find myself lost as I'm pretty new to this and don't know any javascript.

I am trying to add a feature to my website that will include 5 buttons that reveal a div underneath for each button (I have the code for the toggle of this that's okay but!!

This is going to probably sound so easy to you guys but how can I change the background color when the div is clicked on and then reset it if they click one of the other divs, this should work on each of the 5.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.btnmtb{
margin-right: 5px;
touch-action: manipulation;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #1E2327;
padding: 20px 0px;
text-align: center;
}


.btnmtb h1 {
color: #fff;

}

.btnmtb h4 {
color: #fff;

}

.btnmtb p {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;

}

</style>

<div class="disciplines">
<div class="row">
<div class="btnmtb col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 box1">
<p><img src="https://charged.bike/image/catalog/demo/symbols/trail-control.png" width="60%"></p>
<h1>Cross Country</h1>
<h4>Hardtail - 100/120mm</h4>
<p>eMountain Bikes designed for light offroad trails</p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="btnmtb col-md-2 box2">
<p><img src="https://charged.bike/image/catalog/demo/symbols/trail-control.png" width="60%"></p>
<h1>Cross Country</h1>
<h4>FullSus - 100/120mm</h4>
<p>Fast paced eMTB's designed for light trail with rear suspension</p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="btnmtb col-md-2 box3">
<p><img src="https://charged.bike/image/catalog/demo/symbols/trail-control.png" width="60%"></p>
<h1>Trail</h1>
<h4>FullSus - 140/150mm</h4>
<p>Mid Travel - perfect weapons for the more ambitious eMTB rider</p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="btnmtb col-md-2 box4">
<p><img src="https://charged.bike/image/catalog/demo/symbols/trail-control.png" width="60%"></p>
<h1>Enduro</h1>
<h4>FullSus - 160/170mm</h4>
<p>eMountain bikes with long travel designed for the toughest terrain</p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="btnmtb col-md-2 box5">
<p><img src="https://charged.bike/image/catalog/demo/symbols/trail-control.png" width="60%"></p>
<h1>Fatbike</h1>
<h4>Large Tyres - 100/120mm</h4>
<p>The eMountain bikes that look like they have dropped out of a comic book</p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this javascript code (Updated)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('btnmtb');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
           if (elements[j].hasAttribute("style")) {
             elements[j].setAttribute('style', '');
           }
        }
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
     }, false);
};
```

Comment: Exactly what i was after. Amazing. Thankyou so much.

Comment: Hey Sunil, ive just noticed that the background color does not deselect on mobile platforms such as safari. Any idea why this would be ?

Comment: can be seen in action here --> https://charged.bike/ebike-buyers-guides/electric-mountain-bikes

Comment: Hello Adam, thanks to like my answer. I will try to fix this issue on mobile platforms and get back to you.

Comment: @AdamWolfe, I have make some changes. please use this code. Now its working for all platforms

Comment: much better :) thankyou so much you have been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="background-color:red;width:50%" class="element active">
      Red
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;width:50%" class="element">
      Yellow
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:50%" class="element">
      Yellow
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:black;width:50%" class="element">
      Yellow
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:white;width:50%" class="element">
      Yellow
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript+JQuery

```
$(".element").on("click",function()
{
    $(".element").removeClass("active");

  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.active{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelian/gd6y9ykc/1/)